# Canvas rotating when I change it to worldSpace, Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, rotation

I've got a canvas that changes from Overlay to worldSpace when an event occurs, but when it changes to Overlay from worldSpace, the rotation of the canvas is changed, which I don't want it to be.
Images:

[image: Before event, worldSpace]

[image: After event, Overlay]

[image: After event, worldSpace]

As you can see in the order that the images are, it starts with no rotation in worldSpace, then the event occurs changes it to overlay and the rotation is now 140, after the event and I'm back in worldSpace, it is still 140 degrees.

I don't know what is wrong with this. Please help if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because, internally, the Canvas is being transformed into camera space when set to Overlay. That's how it renders. Your solution would be to cache the transform before changing the Render Mode.

Something like this, given a component:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Canvas))]
public class CanvasRenderModeSwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
   private Canvas canvas;
   private Vector3 position;
   private Vector3 scale;
   private Quaternion rotation;

   private void OnEnable()
   {
      canvas = GetComponent<Canvas>();
   }

   public void SetRenderMode(RenderMode renderMode)
   {
      if (renderMode == RenderMode.WorldSpace)
      {
         // Set the render mode before values are reset.
         canvas.renderMode = renderMode;

         // Restore the values.
         transform.position = position;
         transform.rotation = rotation;
         transform.localScale = scale;
      }
      else
      {
         // Cache the values.
         position = transform.position;
         rotation = transform.rotation;
         scale = transform.localScale;

         // Set the render mode after values are cached.
         canvas.renderMode = renderMode;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked well. I knew i was forgetting something simple